# Accessing WebAPI 2 json with DataTables.NET ajax call in MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, datatables-1.10

I have been trying to get DataTables.NET to play nicely with a WebAPI RESTFul service I built and the json being returned does not seem to fit what DataTables is looking for. I have tried the various "server processing" examples along with a few examples I found on the internet like [this one](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2012/10/23/Using-MVC-4-Web-Api-with-jQuery-DataTables.aspx), but I don't want to make the WebAPI call dynamic. I want the API to be self documenting so that other applications and other developers can easily also use the API. So far, here is what I have.

The JSON array after doing a Json.stringify being returned from my API is this:

```
[{"FirstName":"Gregg","LastName":"Coleman"},{"FirstName":"Ryan","LastName":"May"},{"FirstName":"Sean","LastName":"OConnor"},{"FirstName":"Rebecca","LastName":"Coleman"}]
```

The datatable.net code looks like this:

```
$("#data-table").DataTable({

            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            ajax: {

                url: "http://localhost:55180/api/Person",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                dataSrc: function(json)
                {
                    var j = JSON.stringify(json)
                    alert(j);
                    return j;
                }
            }

        });
```

And the HTML looks like this

```
<table id="data-table" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The error I am getting back from dataTables is:

"DataTables warning: table id=data-table - Request unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify which attributes in the JSON that correspond to which columns. Also you need to set `dataSrc` to `''` (because dataTables expects that the array holding the JSON items is named `data`) or simply return the JSON in the `dataSrc` callback. Just setting the `dataSrc` to `''` seems to be the easiest :

```js
$("#data-table").DataTable({
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      columns : [
          { data : 'FirstName' },
          { data : 'LastName' }
      ],    
      ajax: {
          url: "http://localhost:55180/api/Person",
          dataSrc : ''
      }
});
```

now the dataTable is initialized properly -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2jgt3mn8/**