# Trying to use jquery datatable with values coming from database and applying checkbx to it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I am fetching data from database after returning this value binding it in view with html table i want to use jquery datatable instead of html table, link given https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html  with checkbox also added
but not getting idea how to apply it to value coming from database through view.

controller

```
public ActionResult Ipcell()
 {
 List<Ipcell> result = new List<Ipcell>();            
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string qry = "querygiven";
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(qry, conn);
               // command.Parameters.Add(":uug_id_users", Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID]);
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader != null && reader.Read())
                {
                    Ipcell member = new Ipcell();
                    member.CaseId = reader[0].ToString();
                    member.Descripton = reader[1].ToString();
                    member.NoOfBill = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2].ToString());
                    member.TotalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[3].ToString());
                    member.Status = reader[4].ToString();
                    member.CreatedOn =Convert.ToDateTime(reader[5].ToString());
                    member.ClosedOn= Convert.ToDateTime(reader[6].ToString());
                    result.Add(member);                   
                }
return View(result);
}
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<Smart_M.Models.Ipcell>
<table id="ipcelltbl" class="table" Cssclass="gvv table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Raise Bill</th>
                    <th>Close Bill</th>
                    <th>Case ID</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>No of Bills</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>                    
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Created On</th>
                    <th>Closed On</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var d in Model)
            {
                var hid = "hide" + Convert.ToString(d.CaseId);
                   
                    <tr class="">
                        <td><input type="button" name="rbrbill" value="Raise Bill" class="btnrowvalue1" />   </td> 
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="@hid" class="Chkb" name="Chkb" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.CaseId" class="CaseId" name="CaseId" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.Descripton" class="Desc" name="Desc" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.NoOfBill" class="NBill" name="NBill" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.TotalAmount" class="TAmnt" name="TAmnt" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.Status" class="Stat" name="Stat" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.CreatedOn" class="Cron" name="Cron" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@d.ClosedOn" class="Clon" name="Clon"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" style="margin-left:2%;" value="Close Case" class="btnrowvalue2" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }     
                  
            </tbody> 
            
        </table>
```

Layout.cshtml
applied as per jquery datatable

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {     
                  $('#ipcelltbl').DataTable();
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you able to render simple table in your browser?

Comment: @शेखर yes i just want to know how to arrange data coming from db and returning to view  in table so that it will itself bind with table..

Comment: Hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949727/accessing-webapi-2-json-with-datatables-net-ajax-call-in-mvc-application